# Design of an amplifier with emitter degeneration

Tags: amplifier, bjt, gain

I'm trying to solve a question that says to find \$gm\$ and \$R_c\$, considering a gain of 50 using a BC547b transistor. But I can't find a way to calculate these parameters with the information I have. Could someone help me?

The BC547 model:

> *PVDB
> *DATABOOK PHILIPS
> .MODEL BC547B NPN (BF=530 NE=1.3 ISE=9.72F IKF=80M IS=20F VAF=50V
>
> - BR=10 NC=2 ISC=47P IKR=12M VAR=10
> - RB=280 RE=1 RC=40 TR=.3U
> - CJE=12P VJE=.48 MJE=0.5 CJC=6P VJC=.7 MJC=.33 TF=.5N)

So, because of that I'm considering Va = 50V, Is = 20e-15 and Beta = 530. Right?

The circuit of this question:

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 0):

Consider worst case hFE not max do it might be hFE=200 for loading effects on base bias.

- Rc~50*Re
- Rin~hFe(min)*Re
- Ic=10V/(50+1)* Re. *50%
- Vb~0.7V+ Ve(=10V/51=0.2V)=0.9V
- choose base bias with Rin loading effects for 0.9V from 10V

Comment: Tony Stewart: with Rc=50Re=5k and Ic=10V/50Re we have 10V=Vcc across Rc. Instead, we should select Ic=1mA instead of Ic=2mA, don`t you think so?

Comment: Yes sorry Only 5V across Rc to allow AC swing , but 4.5V is better to avoid Vce(sat), and that increases to 2V partial saturationfor high current when Rc=100 and Re=2. Due to variation in hFE effects on THD

Comment: Better design for symmetrical swing is to use Av =>100 then use Rcb/Rsb(series to base) and achieve gain of 50~ with high hFE and full swing9.9V. (1% less due to Av). Unlike OA’s hFE is not high enuf to make gain= Rcb/Rs. Include 10R in source impedance.  Negative feedback is always better than open loop with just Emit. Dej.